# how relationship application software(c#,.net) with Indesign?

Tags: .net, adobe-indesign, idml

How to connect between AdobeIndesign and the application software(c#,.net)?
I want create Preview of idml or indd file into application software?
i can exacute idml or indd file of application software for edite in indesign?
pleas help my.
tanks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you intend to drive InDesign as a service, you need to use the InDesign Server application. The SDK covers every aspects of interoperating with IDS from PHP, JAVA and C#.
Using desktop for such purposes is somehow feasible technically but may violate the EULA if the automation isn't run by the licence  owner himself.

Comment: Can I create an  inddFile of InDesign server with SOAP, .net ?
e.x: input some img
output: indd file
?

Comment: Probably as long as you can work with SOAP in .net. Once the SOAP concern solved, all you have to understand is that driving InDesign Server barely consists in giving the path to the jsx script to be executed and the possible arguments (in your case, the image file path). Be aware that InDesign can't work with http based urls for assets, so you will have a pass a local path reference.

Comment: I want to give a few photos to the indesign server  and get an indd file output that the photos are arranged in.Instead of plugin .Because I wrote the plugin is hard.
Is this possible?

Comment: That mostly what InDesign Server is used for today. A lot of W2P solutions are built upon IDS to output Photobooks, brochures, business cards…